# How to fetch data according to date in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table `truck_data` with columns `truck_no, diesel_filled, source, destination, amount` etc

I want to fetch only `truck_no` and `diesel_filled` in such way that it will show the details of `diesel_filled` in each truck through out the month..

Please tell me the SQL query for that - I had tried this query but it's not working

```
SELECT 
   truck_no, diesel_filled, date 
FROM 
   truck-data 
ORDER BY 
   date
```

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

I want output like this

```
truck_no   1    2   3   4   5   6   7    8   9 etc(date from 1 to 31))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
xyz       25   22  33  33  22  22  22  0   0 (diesel filled in truck order by date)
pqr       25   25  22  11  22  00  22  55  22
abc       21   15  12  14  13  00  22  00  00
```

Comment: Create a fiddle with some sample data,this is really unclear. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: sir pls check is it crt now?

Answer (score 0):

It's still quite unclear what you want. But I think you are mixing presentation and data

```
SELECT truck_no,diesel_filled,date 
FROM truck-data 
ORDER BY date
```

Will give you all rows ordered by date. Presumably you whant some filter on that to only show a specific month.

```
SELECT truck_no,diesel_filled,date 
FROM truck-data 
WHERE date >= 2014-10-05 AND date < 2014-11-01 ORDER BY date
```

To get all the rows for october this year. If date here is a DateTime column.

Then you could change it to:

```
SELECT truck_no,sum(diesel_filled),Day(date) 
FROM truck-data 
WHERE date >= 2014-10-05 AND date < 2014-11-01 
GROUP BY truck_no
ORDER BY date"
```

That would give you only one row per day and truck. If disel_filled is a numeric value of some kind.

Then in your UI you would have to do the presentation in any way you prefer. For example in some kind of pivot table like your description above. 
You could of course do that in SQL as well, but usually that is a job for the presentation layer. 
If you really want to do in SQL you could look into: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx
If you'r using MsSql.